# How to navigate vehicle icon for current location using google map SDK in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm calling direction API to draw the route and trying to move the current location marker icon as user moves the location, But I m facing following problems while implementation.

- while moving the icon, It appears like icon got tilt.
- It doesn't display the actual user position on the route, Icon appears like it is traveling on the side of route.
- My location icon (blue icon) on google map continuously changes its position.

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let direction = newHeading.trueHeading
        lastDriverAngleFromNorth = direction
        self.sourceMarker?.rotation = (lastDriverAngleFromNorth - mapBearing) - bearingValue

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setValue(2, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
                self.gmsmapView?.animate(toBearing: newHeading.magneticHeading)
                    CATransaction.commit()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {

        self.currentLocation = lastLocation
            let zoom = self.gmsmapView?.camera.zoom ?? 20.0
            zoomLevel = zoom
            let destination = CLLocation.init(latitude: viewModel.marker.location[0], longitude: viewModel.marker.location[1])
            let bearing = getBearingBetweenTwoPoints(point1: lastLocation.coordinate, point2: destination.coordinate)
            self.cameraMoveToLocation(toLocation: lastLocation, zoom:zoom, bearing: bearing)
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    mapBearing  = position.bearing
    if let coordinate = self.currentLocation?.coordinate{
            self.rerouteCalculation(currentLocation:coordinate)
    }

    self.sourceMarker?.rotation = (lastDriverAngleFromNorth - mapBearing) - bearingValue
}

func cameraMoveToLocation(toLocation: CLLocation, zoom : Float, bearing : Double) {
    self.gmsmapView?.animate(toLocation: toLocation.coordinate)
    self.sourceMarker?.position = toLocation.coordinate
}
```

Can anyone please help me, I'm stuck here.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to go outside and walk around with a clear view of the sky? This sounds like a GPS precision issue.

Comment: The transparent blue circle around your position marker is the current GPS precision error. It's normal for your position marker to jump around in this area.

Comment: Yes I tried, but my main concern is how to smoothly navigate vehicle icon on the route, with all turns and map bearing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you choose the correct location accuracy for your needs.
[CCLocationAccuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationaccuracy) offers the following options:

- **`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`**:  *<= You should use this when the device is plugged to a power source*
  The highest possible accuracy that uses additional sensor data to
  facilitate navigation apps.
- **`kCLLocationAccuracyBest`**: *<= You should use this when the device runs on battery*
  The best level of accuracy available.
- **`kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters`**: Accurate
  to within ten meters of the desired target.
- **`kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`**: Accurate to
  within one hundred meters.
- **`kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`**: Accurate to the
  nearest kilometer.
- **`kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers`**: Accurate
  to the nearest three kilometers.